# Use regex to lookup and extract a piece of string

Tags: r, regex

I’ve been looking around and haven’t found a clear answer to the following:

In R, what regex-function and what regex-string should I use to lookup an specific pattern and extract a specific part of that pattern?

For example:

Input string:

```
"aaabbs11:00.4.3(1111S)cccsdd(3332d)"
```

Desired output: the part within the brackets after the 11:00.4.3, so

```
# 1111S
```

Comment: could you be more specific? this would give you the desired answer but I don't know how the rest of your cases look like `sub(".*?\\((.*?)\\).*","\\1",string)`

Comment: You need to give more details. With regexp the devil is in the detail. Is it always the first expression in round brackets that you're trying to extract? Or is it always the expression after `"11:00.4.3"`? Or...?

Comment: In the case above I wanted the part in the brackets after the code 11:00.4.3. However in the string i’m Working with there are more codes (11:00.7.6 for example) that also function as a prefix of a part in brackets that I also would like to extract. So maybe I should ask for the regex-string that looks for a specific prefix code and then extracts the part within the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first string in parenthesis after \d\d:\d\d.\d.\d, then

```
.*?\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d\.\d.*?\((.*?)\)
```

If the number of digits can vary, replace `{2}` with `*`, and add `*` after the `\d` without any quantifiers.